# $\overline{C} = \overline{int(C)}$, C closed, in normed space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Does the property $\overline{C} = \overline{int(C)}$ hold for $C$, a closed subset of a normed space such that $int(C) \neq \emptyset$? I was thinking that perhaps this is false. For example, take the space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual norm and topology. Then take $C$ to be a line and a closed ball (disjoint).

But then $\overline{int(C)}$ is just the closed ball...

Comment: Is $C$ an arbitrary set here? The property is certainly false for $C=(\mathbb Q\cup(0,1))\subseteq\mathbb R$.

Comment: Hmm, and your own counterexample is _also_ a counterexample. But now I'm unsure what you're actually _asking_...

Comment: Yes, $C$ is an arbitrary subset except for the condition that $int(C) \neq \emptyset$. However I think that last condition makes your counterexample invalid since the rationals have empty interior.

Comment: x @Luke: The interior of $\mathbb Q\cup(0,1)$ is $(0,1)$ which is not empty.

Comment: You can always take a non-empty open ball $B$ and a point $p \not \in \overline B$ and let $C=\overline C=\overline { \{p\}\cup B}=\{p\}\cup \overline B.$  Then $\overline {int (C)}=\overline B\ne \overline C$. For example let $B$ be the open unit ball centered at $0$ and let $\|p\|=2.$

Comment: If $\overline C=\overline {int(C)}$ then $\overline C$ is called a  regular-closed set. If $B=int (\overline B)$ then $B$ is called a regular-open set.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ah sorry, you're right, I read that as intersection, not union.